# Oracle INSTR backward in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I am trying to find a way in oracle SQL to take all the text after the 1st "/" FROM THE RIGHT to the 4th "/".  I need to do this in one SQL statement..

```
table name: access_log
col name: download
value: Download file:/webdocs/data/groupXXX/case/03_28_54_9_0000011856.pdf
```

I am trying to end up with

```
case
```

then a count of how many matches?  can this be done?

Comment: Given REVERSE reverses a string, maybe you can reverse, match from the left, reverse?

Comment: Actually, it has to be possible with (possibly multiple) REGEXP_SUBSTR?

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand what you want to count exactly

Answer (score 1):

```
select regexp_replace('Download file:/webdocs/data/groupXXX/case/03_28_54_9_0000011856.pdf', 
                      '.*/([^/]+)/[^/]*$', '\1') from dual;
```

Comment: I dont need from the hard code values I need it from the database value

Comment: @JMS perhaps you could provide more sample records to test either approach provided.

Comment: I did to find the value and count how many times it is in the database

Answer (score 0):

A Simple `SUBSTR` approach works from Oracle 10g+

```
select TRIM(BOTH '/' FROM 
          substr(
                  download,
                  INSTR(download,'/',1,4),
                  INSTR(download,'/',1,5)-INSTR(download,'/',1,4)
                 )
           )
FROM ACCESS_LOG;
```

And count could be,

```
SELECT
COUNT(
         CASE WHEN TRIM(BOTH '/' FROM 
                        substr(
                                download,
                                INSTR(download,'/',1,4),
                                INSTR(download,'/',1,5)-INSTR(download,'/',1,4)
                               )
                         ) = 'case'
         THEN
             1
         END
       ) COUNT_MATCHED
FROM 
     ACCESS_LOG;
```

Comment: i need this coming from the database not the hard coded value

Comment: huh? I dont understand