# Anyway way to change this Oracle SQL statment to use regs?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, substring

I am working on some Oracle SQL and I am new to it.. I have data in my table 'web_access_log' the col name is 'activity'.  I need to get the data that is save in the col between the the 4th and 5th "/" or it would be been if I can do it from right to let and get the data from the 1 to 2nd "/" from right to left!  Below is a SQL statement that works but from left to right.. I really need right to left and maybe in REGEX to make it easyer?

```
Table: web_access_log
col name: activity
Sample value: Download file:/webdocs/data/groupXXX/case/03_28_54_9_0000011856.pdf
```

This is what I have now

```
SQL:
select  SUBSTR(activity, INSTR(activity, '/', 1, 4) + 1, INSTR(activity, '/', 1, 5) - INSTR(activity, '/', 1, 4) -1) AS FILENAME,
COUNT (SUBSTR(activity, INSTR(activity, '/', 1, 4) + 1, INSTR(activity, '/', 1, 5) - INSTR(activity, '/', 1, 4)-1)) AS DOWNLOADS
FROM sa.web_access_log where application_id = 5339 and to_char(time_stamp, 'mm/yyyy') = '04/2011'
GROUP BY SUBSTR(activity, INSTR(activity, '/', 1, 4) + 1, INSTR(activity, '/', 1, 5) - INSTR(activity, '/', 1, 4) -1)
ORDER BY DOWNLOADS DESC;
```

Comment: Your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112171/oracle-instr-backward-in-oracle-sql) have answers with both regex and normal approach!

Comment: This fails in your code `to_char(time_stamp, 'mm/yyyy') = '04/2011'`

Comment: that code works here but its from left to right.. I need right to left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar approach , but gets the '/' from right to left (backwards)

`INSTR(download,'/',-1,2)` ==> Gets the last but one occurence of  '/' == -1 here means in reverse

**Function to extract the value:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EXTRACT_FOLDER (str VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR 
AS
ret_str  VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    BEGIN
      ret_str := TRIM(BOTH '/' FROM 
              substr(
                      str,
                      INSTR(str,'/',-1,2),
                      INSTR(str,'/',-1,1)-INSTR(str,'/',-1,2)
                     )
               );

    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
     ret_str := NULL;
    END;
    return ret_str;
END;
/
```

**Your Query:**

```
select COUNT(1)
FROM ACCESS_LOG
WHERE EXTRACT_FOLDER(download) = 'case';
```

AND this would list of the values and it is count.

```
select EXTRACT_FOLDER(download), COUNT(1)
FROM ACCESS_LOG
GROUP BY EXTRACT_FOLDER(download);
```

**Without function:**

```
select COUNT(1)
FROM ACCESS_LOG
WHERE TRIM(BOTH '/' FROM 
              substr(
                      download,
                      INSTR(download,'/',-1,2),
                      INSTR(download,'/',-1,1)-INSTR(download,'/',-1,2)
                     )
               ) = 'case';
```

**Regex Approach**

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM ACCESS_LOG
   WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(download, '(.*/(.*)/.*$)','\2') = 'case';
```

**How this works??**

`.*` means some character.. Zero or more occurence
`$` means end of line
`/.*$` means strings starts with a / till end of line..`/03_28_54_9_0000011856.pdf`
`.*/.*/.*$` means somestring with 2 slashes to end of line. Which is what we are interested..But this brings us the entire line...

Now, the trick is the brackets....
`(.*/(.*)/.*$)` will become `(/webdocs/data/groupXXX/(case)/03_28_54_9_0000011856.pdf)`

Note the braces.. Regexp replace will now have `\1` as the one within outside bracket, the entire line..
And \2 will be haing `case`.

As we just use `\2` , the entire expression is replaces with `case`.

;

Comment: but this is using the hard coded value.. I need it coming from database and also grouping and counting like the example above

Comment: I dont know why this is working ion SQL Fiddle but not Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: @JMS can you try the one I updated now. Should be easily maintainable!

Comment: i cant I need it all in once SQL like my example

Comment: @JMS also added regexp approach.

Comment: i dont see how this is giving me the output

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but this seems to work:

`select
  regexp_replace(activity, '^.*/(.*)/.*$', '\2')
from
  (select 'Download file:/webdocs/data/groupXXX/case/03_28_54_9_0000011856.pdf' as activity from dual)
;`

This returns:

`case`

which is the text between the first and second "/" from the right.

Since Oracles regex is greedy by default, the first ".*" slurps up as much of the string as possible while honoring the rest of the regex, which includes to explicit slashes.  So the result is that "\2" is the text between the last two slashes.